# Find all positions of all matches of one vector of values in second vector

Tags: r, match, vectorization

I need to find all positions in my vector corresponding to any of values of another vector:

```
needles <- c(4, 3, 9)
hay <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7)
mymatches(needles, hay) # should give vector: 2 3 5
```

Is there any predefined function allowing to do this?

Comment: You want to *vectorize the match operator/function*.

Comment: FYI, the [`match()` fn and `%in%` operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) are the same thing. And they're vectorized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
which(hay %in% needles) # 2 3 5
```

Comment: The old hay in a needlestack :)

Comment: But won't that return first matches only? If 4, 3, and 9 occurred repeatedly in hay we wouldn't see those repeats, right?

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON no, it should return all matches.

Answer (score 4):

R already has the the [`match()` function / `%in%` operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html), which are the same thing, and they're vectorized. Your solution:

```
which(!is.na(match(hay, needles)))
[1] 2 3 5
```

or the shorter syntax `which(hay %in% needles)` as @jalapic showed.

With `match()`, if you wanted to, you could see which specific value was matched at each position...

```
match(hay, needles)
[1] NA  2  1 NA  2 NA
```

or just a logical vector of where the matches occurred:

```
!is.na(match(hay, needles))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: `match` only returns the positions of **(first)** matches, while using `which(hay %in% needles)`, all matches are identified.